# Keras Callback EarlyStopping comparing training and validation loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm fitting a neural network in *Python* *Keras*.

To avoid overfitting I would like to monitor the training/validation loss and create a proper callback which stops computations when training loss is too much less than validation loss.

An example of a callback is:

```
callback = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', value=45, verbose=0, mode='auto')]
```

**Is there any way to stop training when training loss too little compared to validation loss?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom callback class for your purpose.

I have created one that should correspond to your need :

```
class CustomEarlyStopping(Callback):
    def __init__(self, ratio=0.0,
                 patience=0, verbose=0):
        super(EarlyStopping, self).__init__()

        self.ratio = ratio
        self.patience = patience
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        self.monitor_op = np.greater

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.wait = 0  # Allow instances to be re-used

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_val = logs.get('val_loss')
        current_train = logs.get('loss')
        if current_val is None:
            warnings.warn('Early stopping requires %s available!' %
                          (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)

        # If ratio current_loss / current_val_loss > self.ratio
        if self.monitor_op(np.divide(current_train,current_val),self.ratio):
            self.wait = 0
        else:
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
            self.wait += 1

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0 and self.verbose > 0:
            print('Epoch %05d: early stopping' % (self.stopped_epoch))
```

I took the liberty to interpret that you wanted to stop if the ratio between the `train_loss` and the `validation_loss` goes under a certain **ratio** threshold. This ratio argument should be between `0.0` and `1.0`. However, `1.0` is dangerous as the validation loss and the training loss might fluctuate a lot in an erratic way at the beginning of the training.

You can add a patience argument which will wait to see if the breaking of your threshold is staying for a certain number of epochs.

The way to use this is for exampe :

```
callbacks = [CustomEarlyStopping(ratio=0.5, patience=2, verbose=1), 
            ... Other callbacks ...]
...
model.fit(..., callbacks=callbacks)
```

In this case it will stop if the training loss stays lower than `0.5*val_loss` for more than 2 epochs.

Does that help you?

Comment: Very welcome :) I just took the source code of EarlyStopping class and adapted it... feel free to edit for your needs, there's no magic there!

Comment: Thanks for this example, but using tensorflow.keras and py3.5 I'm getting the error `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: I think it's a typo that should be `super(CustomEarlyStopping, self).__init__()`