# Using super in custom Keras callback

Tags: tensorflow, callback, keras, python-3.5, super

I'm not very familiar with python `super` functionality and inheritance. I tried to copy and use the keras custom callback example I found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470604/keras-callback-earlystopping-comparing-training-and-validation-loss), but I'm getting the error:

```
    super(EarlyStopping, self).__init__()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Here's the example code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping

class OverfitEarlyStopping(Callback):
    def __init__(self, ratio=0.0,
                 patience=0, verbose=0):
        super(EarlyStopping, self).__init__()

        self.ratio = ratio
        self.patience = patience
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        self.monitor_op = np.greater

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.wait = 0  # Allow instances to be re-used

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current_val = logs.get('val_loss')
        current_train = logs.get('loss')
        if current_val is None:
            warnings.warn('Early stopping requires %s available!' %
                          (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)

        # If ratio current_loss / current_val_loss > self.ratio
        if self.monitor_op(np.divide(current_train,current_val),self.ratio):
            self.wait = 0
        else:
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
            self.wait += 1

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0 and self.verbose > 0:
            print('Epoch %05d: early stopping due to overfitting.' % (self.stopped_epoch))

overfit_callback = OverfitEarlyStopping(ratio=0.8, patience=3, verbose=1)
```

I'm using Python 3.5 and tensorflow.keras. Has the use of super changed in the versions I'm using, or was this callback written incorrectly in the first place?

Comment: It should be `super(OverfitEarlyStopping, self).__init__()`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I guess it was just a simple typo in the original post.

Comment: I found that program creek sometimes has good examples. ex: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104417/keras.callbacks.Callback

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to initialize super when extending the base class `keras.callbacks.Callback`. The model is passed to the functions you choose to override. You can see some examples [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

Also, why not use [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping)

Comment: Thanks. I’d like to stop when overfitting which requires knowledge of loss and val_loss

Comment: When you initialize ```EarlyStopping``` you can set the monitor to ```loss``` or ```val_loss```

Comment: The network is overfitting if loss is going down at a higher rate than val_loss, so you need to monitor the ratio of the two. You wouldn’t want a network where val_loss is going down by a negligible amount each epoch while loss is going down drastically.