# Tensorflow: how to save a model before the end of optimization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm using `ScipyOptimizerInterface` for training a `tensorflow` model. (`tensorflow 1.13.1`)

During the process of training, if the `loss` value is below a threshold, I want the training process to stop and save the model right before the threshold was crossed.

Below is the script that I tried. The idea is to raise an exception to exit `optimizer.minimize`, then save the model using `tf.train.Saver`.

However, this does not work. As you can see by comparing **the initial `loss` value** and **the `loss` value computed by the saved model**. The two values are the same which indicates it is the initial random model that is saved, not the desired model.

From @Patol75's answer, I understand the best model is not saved because the updated `tf.Variables` dies when the training session is interpreted.

How can the desired model be saved?

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.opt import ScipyOptimizerInterface

class test(Exception):
    pass

def construct_graph():
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        x = tf.placeholder('float', shape = [None, 1])
        w = tf.get_variable('w_0', shape = [1, 1], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        b = tf.get_variable('b_0', shape = [1], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        y_out = tf.matmul(x, w) + b
        y = tf.placeholder('float', shape = [None, 1])
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_out))
    return graph, x, y, loss

# create example datasets
x_train = np.linspace(1, 6, 100) + 0.1 * np.random.random(100)
x_train = x_train.reshape(100, 1)
y_train = np.sin(x_train)
x_val = np.linspace(6, 11, 100)
x_val = x_val.reshape(100, 1)
y_val = np.sin(x_val)

tf.reset_default_graph()
graph, x, y, loss = construct_graph()
feeddict_train = {x: x_train, y: y_train}
feeddict_val = {x: x_val, y: y_val}

with graph.as_default():

    def step_callbackfun(x):
        global iteration
        train_part, val_part = valfunc_train(x), valfunc_val(x) 
        print('%10.5f %10.5f' % (*train_part, *val_part))
        iteration += 1
        if iteration == 5:
            raise test()

    sess = tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, method='l-BFGS-b')

    iteration = 0
    valfunc_train = optimizer._make_eval_func(tensors=loss, session=sess, feed_dict=feeddict_train, fetches=[])
    valfunc_val = optimizer._make_eval_func(tensors=loss, session=sess, feed_dict=feeddict_val, fetches=[])

    print('The initial loss is %f' % sess.run(loss, feeddict_train))    
    try:
        optimizer.minimize(sess, feeddict_train, step_callback=step_callbackfun)
    except test:
        saver.save(sess, 'model/model.ckpt')
        graph2, x2, y2, loss2 = construct_graph()
        with tf.Session(graph=graph2) as sess2:
            feeddict_two = {x2: x_train, y2: y_train}
            sess2.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            saver2 = tf.train.Saver()
            saver2.restore(sess2, 'model/model.ckpt')
            loss_val2 = sess2.run(loss2, feeddict_two)
            print('Outside', loss_val2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface#minimize)

> Variables subject to optimization are updated in-place at the end of optimization.

This is why interrupting the process the way you do does give you the original value. I have never used TensorFlow, but the keyword `loss_callback` sounds promising.

> A function to be called every time the loss and gradients are computed, with evaluated fetches supplied as positional arguments.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470604/keras-callback-earlystopping-comparing-training-and-validation-loss).

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand how `loss_callback` sounds promising, can you provide some hints?

Comment: Well, what if you can access the value of 'loss' in the call to the function provided to `loss_callback`? Just an idea though, might not be possible. As I said, never used TensorFlow myself. But also, have you had a look at the other post I linked? It seems like exactly what you want.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved by that. My goal is to save a model before it reaches the end of the optimization. I have tried to save the model in the callback function, but still, it is the initial model that is saved.

Comment: I see. Well, my knowledge is pretty limited then, so you will probably need the help of someone else. I still found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50852627/10640534), which describes multiple ways to save the model, hopefully it can help.